# how to convert vbscript Mid function to javascript with 2 arguments?

Tags: javascript, vbscript

```
    nHighlightedRow = Mid(string, 2, 11)
```

I can convert this like ,

```
    var nHighlightedRow = string.subStr(2-1,11)
```

but I have to convert this,

```
    nHighlightedRow = Mid(string, 11)
```

can I convert this as follow ?

```
    var nHighlightedRow = string.subStr(0,11)
```

Comment: try it and see for yourself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, `Mid(string,11)` extracts from character 11 to the end of the string and `string.substring(0,11)` extracts from character 1, you will need `string.substring(10)`

Comment: it works, thank you very much lynamc. is it a overidden function of substring ?

Comment: Yes, you can say (StartIndex, Length) or just (StartIndex)

Answer (score 0):

no.

it would be `string.substring(11-1)`.